# Beautifulsoup: How to find a string if tag or element not known?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

As it says all. Is there anyway to search entire DOM for a specific text, for instance **CAPTCHA** word?

Comment: Do you have any consistent value? Class, id, structure?

Comment: NO, I don't know Tag/Element at all. Only strig

Comment: If there's a particular design to the string, you can use a regex expression to parse it, though it may be a bit less reliable.

See http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#a-regular-expression

Alternately, you can match against any function which can return true/false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find` and specify the [`text`](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#the-text-argument) argument:

> With text you can search for strings instead of tags. As with name and
>   the keyword arguments, you can pass in a string, a regular expression,
>   a list, a function, or the value True.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <div>test1</div>
... <div class="myclass1">test2</div>
... <div class="myclass2">CAPTCHA</div>
... <div class="myclass3">test3</div>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find(text='CAPTCHA').parent
<div class="myclass2">CAPTCHA</div>
```

If `CAPTCHA` is just a part of a text, you can pass a `lambda` function into `text` and check if `CAPTCHA` is inside the tag text:

```
>>> data = """
... <div>test1</div>
... <div class="myclass1">test2</div>
... <div class="myclass2">Here CAPTCHA is a part of a sentence</div>
... <div class="myclass3">test3</div>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find(text=lambda x: 'CAPTCHA' in x).parent
<div class="myclass2">Here CAPTCHA is a part of a sentence</div>
```

Or, the same can be achieved if you pass a regular expression into `text`:

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile('CAPTCHA')).parent
<div class="myclass2">Here CAPTCHA is a part of a sentence</div>
```